# Determining whether a user/current user can create a field on a custom object?

Tags: custom-field

I have a custom object called Data__c.I want to create fields on that object dynamically.So I want to check whether the user who is trying to create fields has enough permissions ?

Comment: Do you mean do they have permission to populate data into a field, or actually adding *new custom fields* (with a name, label, type, default etc.etc.) on your object dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

To [create a custom field](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=adding_fields.htm&language=nl), a user must have the [`Customize Application` permission](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gnpFAAQ). Now, to get that information, you will need to query the [`Profile`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm) of the currently logged in user. Specifically, you are interested in the `PermissionsCustomizeApplication` field. It is stored as a boolean and will return a `true` or `false`. That code in Apex may look like:

```
Profile loggedInUserProfile = [SELECT PermissionsCustomizeApplication FROM Profile WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()];

if(loggedInUserProfile.PermissionsCustomizeApplication){
    // Do your logic here
}
```

Note, in the above code I also referenced the [`UserInfo` class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm). Just wanted to provide a link for your reference.